# Как добавить условия в калькулятор?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть калькулятор стоимости постройки дома. Сейчас он просто умножает площадь дома на стоимость работ, которая указана в скрипте. Нужно добавить цены для одноэтажного дома и двухэтажного. Выбрал в списке одноэтажный дом и все расчеты будут по ценам для одноэтажного дома. Для двухэтажного по ценам для двухэтажного. Например, фундамент для одноэтажного будет стоить 5000, а для двухэтажного 3000 итд. Как это сделать?
Вот код:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 var s_doma = parseInt($("#s_dom").val()); //площадь дома
 //Фундамент
 var fund_bezf = 0;
 var fund_stolb = 3200;
 var fund_fbs = 4100;
 var fund_lenta = 4800;
 var fund_plita = 5350;
 var fund_all_bezf = 0;
 var fund_all_stolb = 0;
 var fund_all_fbs = 0;
 var fund_all_lenta = 0;
 var fund_all_plita = 0;
 var cena_fund = 0;
 //Перекрытие цоколя
 var per_cok_zhbi = 2100;
 var per_cok_monolit = 4600;
 var per_cok_derevo = 1600;
 var per_cok_all_zhbi = 0;
 var per_cok_all_monolit = 0;
 var per_cok_all_derevo = 0;
 var cena_per_cok = 0;
 //Стены
 var stena_kirpich_250 = 6200;
 var stena_kirpich_370 = 7600;
 var stena_kirpich_640 = 9100;
 var stena_kirpich_520 = 8700;
 var stena_teplaya_keramika = 8300;
 var stena_gazobeton = 5600;
 var stena_brus_150 = 6500;
 var stena_brus_200 = 7200;
 var stena_karkasnyy_dom = 5600;
 var stena_dom_srub = 7900;
 var stena_all_kirpich_250 = 0;
 var stena_all_kirpich_370 = 0;
 var stena_all_kirpich_640 = 0;
 var stena_all_kirpich_520 = 0;
 var stena_all_teplaya_keramika = 0;
 var stena_all_gazobeton = 0;
 var stena_all_brus_150 = 0;
 var stena_all_brus_200 = 0;
 var stena_all_karkasnyy_dom = 0;
 var stena_all_dom_srub = 0;
 var cena_stena = 0;
 //Перекрытие межэтажное
 var per_et_zhbi = 2100;
 var per_et_monolit = 4600;
 var per_et_derevo = 1600;
 var per_et_all_zhbi = 0;
 var per_et_all_monolit = 0;
 var per_et_all_derevo = 0;
 var cena_per_et = 0;
 //Чердачное перекрытие
 var per_ch_zhbi = 2100;
 var per_ch_monolit = 4600;
 var per_ch_derevo = 1600;
 var per_ch_all_zhbi = 0;
 var per_ch_all_monolit = 0;
 var per_ch_all_derevo = 0;
 var cena_per_ch = 0;
 //Крыша
 var krysha_metallocherepica = 6100;
 var krysha_ondulin = 4200;
 var krysha_proflist = 5100;
 var krysha_ker_plitka = 7700;
 var krysha_myagkaya_cher = 6500;
 var krysha_all_metallocherepica = 0;
 var krysha_all_ondulin = 0;
 var krysha_all_proflist = 0;
 var krysha_all_ker_plitka = 0;
 var krysha_all_myagkaya_cher = 0;
 var cena_krysha = 0;
 //Отделка фасада
 var fasad_sh_setka = 2800;
 var fasad_utepl_pokraska = 5600;
 var fasad_decor = 3700;
 var fasad_kirpich = 4600;
 var fasad_sayding = 2600;
 var fasad_all_sh_setka = 0;
 var fasad_all_utepl_pokraska = 0;
 var fasad_all_decor = 0;
 var fasad_all_kirpich = 0;
 var fasad_all_sayding = 0;
 var cena_fasad = 0;
 var cena_all;

 $("#s_dom").on("input", function () {
  s_doma = parseInt($("#s_dom").val()); //площадь дома
  //Фундамент
  if($("#fund_1 img").hasClass("active") == true){
   fund_all_bezf = 0;
   cena_fund = fund_all_bezf;
   $("#print_form .block_stroy p.fund>span").html(fund_all_bezf);
  }
  if($("#fund_2 img").hasClass("active") == true){
   fund_all_stolb = s_doma * fund_stolb;
   cena_fund = fund_all_stolb;
   $("#print_form .block_stroy p.fund>span").html(fund_all_stolb);
  }
  if($("#fund_3 img").hasClass("active") == true){
   fund_all_fbs = s_doma * fund_fbs;
   cena_fund = fund_all_fbs;
   $("#print_form .block_stroy p.fund>span").html(fund_all_fbs);
  }
  if($("#fund_4 img").hasClass("active") == true){
   fund_all_lenta = s_doma * fund_lenta;
   cena_fund = fund_all_lenta;
   $("#print_form .block_stroy p.fund>span").html(fund_all_lenta);
  }
  if($("#fund_5 img").hasClass("active") == true){
   fund_all_plita = s_doma * fund_plita;
   cena_fund = fund_all_plita;
   $("#print_form .block_stroy p.fund>span").html(fund_all_plita);
  }
  //Перекрытие цоколя
  if($("#per_cok_1 img").hasClass("active") == true){
   per_cok_all_zhbi = s_doma * per_cok_zhbi;
   cena_per_cok = per_cok_all_zhbi;
   $("#print_form .block_stroy p.per_cok>span").html(per_cok_all_zhbi);
  }
  if($("#per_cok_2 img").hasClass("active") == true){
   per_cok_all_monolit = s_doma * per_cok_monolit;
   cena_per_cok = per_cok_all_monolit;
   $("#print_form .block_stroy p.per_cok>span").html(per_cok_all_monolit);
  }
  if($("#per_cok_3 img").hasClass("active") == true){
   per_cok_all_derevo = s_doma * per_cok_derevo;
   cena_per_cok = per_cok_all_derevo;
   $("#print_form .block_stroy p.per_cok>span").html(per_cok_all_derevo);
  }
  //Стены
  if($("#stena_1 img").hasClass("active") == true){
   stena_all_kirpich_250 = s_doma * stena_kirpich_250;
   cena_stena = stena_all_kirpich_250;
   $("#print_form .block_stroy p.stena>span").html(stena_all_kirpich_250);
  }
  if($("#stena_2 img").hasClass("active") == true){
   stena_all_kirpich_370 = s_doma * stena_kirpich_370;
   cena_stena = stena_all_kirpich_370;
   $("#print_form .block_stroy p.stena>span").html(stena_all_kirpich_370);
  }
  if($("#stena_3 img").hasClass("active") == true){
   stena_all_kirpich_640 = s_doma * stena_kirpich_640;
   cena_stena = stena_all_kirpich_640;
   $("#print_form .block_stroy p.stena>span").html(stena_all_kirpich_640);
  }
  if($("#stena_4 img").hasClass("active") == true){
   stena_all_kirpich_520 = s_doma * stena_kirpich_520;
   cena_stena = stena_all_kirpich_520;
   $("#print_form .block_stroy p.stena>span").html(stena_all_kirpich_520);
  }
  if($("#stena_5 img").hasClass("active") == true){
   stena_all_teplaya_keramika = s_doma * stena_teplaya_keramika;
   cena_stena = stena_all_teplaya_keramika;
   $("#print_form .block_stroy p.stena>span").html(stena_all_teplaya_keramika);
  }
  if($("#stena_6 img").hasClass("active") == true){
   stena_all_gazobeton = s_doma * stena_gazobeton;
   cena_stena = stena_all_gazobeton;
   $("#print_form .block_stroy p.stena>span").html(stena_all_gazobeton);
  }
  if($("#stena_7 img").hasClass("active") == true){
   stena_all_brus_150 = s_doma * stena_brus_150;
   cena_stena = stena_all_brus_150;
   $("#print_form .block_stroy p.stena>span").html(stena_all_brus_150);
  }
  if($("#stena_8 img").hasClass("active") == true){
   stena_all_brus_200 = s_doma * stena_brus_200;
   cena_stena = stena_all_brus_200;
   $("#print_form .block_stroy p.stena>span").html(stena_all_brus_200);
  }
  if($("#stena_9 img").hasClass("active") == true){
   stena_all_karkasnyy_dom = s_doma * stena_karkasnyy_dom;
   cena_stena = stena_all_karkasnyy_dom;
   $("#print_form .block_stroy p.stena>span").html(stena_all_karkasnyy_dom);
  }
  if($("#stena_10 img").hasClass("active") == true){
   stena_all_dom_srub = s_doma * stena_dom_srub;
   cena_stena = stena_all_dom_srub;
   $("#print_form .block_stroy p.stena>span").html(stena_all_dom_srub);
  }
  //Перекрытие межэтажное
  if($("#per_et_1 img").hasClass("active") == true){
   per_et_all_zhbi = s_doma * per_et_zhbi;
   cena_per_et = per_et_all_zhbi;
   $("#print_form .block_stroy p.per_et>span").html(per_et_all_zhbi);
  }
  if($("#per_et_2 img").hasClass("active") == true){
   per_et_all_monolit = s_doma * per_et_monolit;
   cena_per_et = per_et_all_monolit;
   $("#print_form .block_stroy p.per_et>span").html(per_et_all_monolit);
  }
  if($("#per_et_3 img").hasClass("active") == true){
   per_et_all_derevo = s_doma * per_et_derevo;
   cena_per_et = per_et_all_derevo;
   $("#print_form .block_stroy p.per_et>span").html(per_et_all_derevo);
  }
  //Чердачное перекрытие
  if($("#per_ch_1 img").hasClass("active") == true){
   per_ch_all_zhbi = s_doma * per_ch_zhbi;
   cena_per_ch = per_ch_all_zhbi;
   $("#print_form .block_stroy p.per_ch>span").html(per_ch_all_zhbi);
  }
  if($("#per_ch_2 img").hasClass("active") == true){
   per_ch_all_monolit = s_doma * per_ch_monolit;
   cena_per_ch = per_ch_all_monolit;
   $("#print_form .block_stroy p.per_ch>span").html(per_ch_all_monolit);
  }
  if($("#per_ch_3 img").hasClass("active") == true){
   per_ch_all_derevo = s_doma * per_ch_derevo;
   cena_per_ch = per_ch_all_derevo;
   $("#print_form .block_stroy p.per_ch>span").html(per_ch_all_derevo);
  }
  //Крыша
  if($("#krysha_1 img").hasClass("active") == true){
   krysha_all_metallocherepica = s_doma * krysha_metallocherepica;
   cena_krysha = krysha_all_metallocherepica;
   $("#print_form .block_stroy p.krysha>span").html(krysha_all_metallocherepica);
  }
  if($("#krysha_2 img").hasClass("active") == true){
   krysha_all_ondulin = s_doma * krysha_ondulin;
   cena_krysha = krysha_all_ondulin;
   $("#print_form .block_stroy p.krysha>span").html(krysha_all_ondulin);
  }
  if($("#krysha_3 img").hasClass("active") == true){
   krysha_all_proflist = s_doma * krysha_proflist;
   cena_krysha = krysha_all_proflist;
   $("#print_form .block_stroy p.krysha>span").html(krysha_all_proflist);
  }
  if($("#krysha_4 img").hasClass("active") == true){
   krysha_all_ker_plitka = s_doma * krysha_ker_plitka;
   cena_krysha = krysha_all_ker_plitka;
   $("#print_form .block_stroy p.krysha>span").html(krysha_all_ker_plitka);
  }
  if($("#krysha_5 img").hasClass("active") == true){
   krysha_all_myagkaya_cher = s_doma * krysha_myagkaya_cher;
   cena_krysha = krysha_all_myagkaya_cher;
   $("#print_form .block_stroy p.krysha>span").html(krysha_all_myagkaya_cher);
  }
  //Отделка фасада
  if($("#fasad_1 img").hasClass("active") == true){
   fasad_all_sh_setka = s_doma * fasad_sh_setka;
   cena_fasad = fasad_all_sh_setka;
   $("#print_form .block_stroy p.fasad>span").html(fasad_all_sh_setka);
  }
  if($("#fasad_2 img").hasClass("active") == true){
   fasad_all_utepl_pokraska = s_doma * fasad_utepl_pokraska;
   cena_fasad = fasad_all_utepl_pokraska;
   $("#print_form .block_stroy p.fasad>span").html(fasad_all_utepl_pokraska);
  }
  if($("#fasad_3 img").hasClass("active") == true){
   fasad_all_decor = s_doma * fasad_decor;
   cena_fasad = fasad_all_decor;
   $("#print_form .block_stroy p.fasad>span").html(fasad_all_decor);
  }
  if($("#fasad_4 img").hasClass("active") == true){
   fasad_all_kirpich = s_doma * fasad_kirpich;
   cena_fasad = fasad_all_kirpich;
   $("#print_form .block_stroy p.fasad>span").html(fasad_all_kirpich);
  }
  if($("#fasad_5 img").hasClass("active") == true){
   fasad_all_sayding = s_doma * fasad_sayding;
   cena_fasad = fasad_all_sayding;
   $("#print_form .block_stroy p.fasad>span").html(fasad_all_sayding);
  }
  cena_all = cena_fund + cena_per_cok + cena_stena + cena_per_et + cena_per_ch + cena_krysha + cena_fasad;
  $("#dom_rez_price_rab").html(cena_all);
 });
 //
 //
 $("#print_form .block_stroy_fund .block_img").on("click", "img", function(){
  $("#print_form .block_stroy_fund .block_img>img").removeClass("active"); //удаляем класс во всех вкладках
  $("#print_form .block_stroy_fund .block_img>img").css("opacity", "0.5");
  $(this).addClass("active"); //добавляем класс текущей (нажатой)
  $(this).css("opacity", "1");
  //Фундамент
  if($("#fund_1 img").hasClass("active") == true){
   fund_all_bezf = 0;
   cena_fund = fund_all_bezf;
   $("#print_form .block_stroy p.fund>span").html(fund_all_bezf);
  }
  if($("#fund_2 img").hasClass("active") == true){
   fund_all_stolb = s_doma * fund_stolb;
   cena_fund = fund_all_stolb;
   $("#print_form .block_stroy p.fund>span").html(fund_all_stolb);
  }
  if($("#fund_3 img").hasClass("active") == true){
   fund_all_fbs = s_doma * fund_fbs;
   cena_fund = fund_all_fbs;
   $("#print_form .block_stroy p.fund>span").html(fund_all_fbs);
  }
  if($("#fund_4 img").hasClass("active") == true){
   fund_all_lenta = s_doma * fund_lenta;
   cena_fund = fund_all_lenta;
   $("#print_form .block_stroy p.fund>span").html(fund_all_lenta);
  }
  if($("#fund_5 img").hasClass("active") == true){
   fund_all_plita = s_doma * fund_plita;
   cena_fund = fund_all_plita;
   $("#print_form .block_stroy p.fund>span").html(fund_all_plita);
  }
 });
 $("#print_form .block_stroy_per_cok .block_img").on("click", "img", function(){
  $("#print_form .block_stroy_per_cok .block_img>img").removeClass("active"); //удаляем класс во всех вкладках
  $("#print_form .block_stroy_per_cok .block_img>img").css("opacity", "0.5");
  $(this).addClass("active"); //добавляем класс текущей (нажатой)
  $(this).css("opacity", "1");
  //Перекрытие цоколя
  if($("#per_cok_1 img").hasClass("active") == true){
   per_cok_all_zhbi = s_doma * per_cok_zhbi;
   cena_per_cok = per_cok_all_zhbi;
   $("#print_form .block_stroy p.per_cok>span").html(per_cok_all_zhbi);
  }
  if($("#per_cok_2 img").hasClass("active") == true){
   per_cok_all_monolit = s_doma * per_cok_monolit;
   cena_per_cok = per_cok_all_monolit;
   $("#print_form .block_stroy p.per_cok>span").html(per_cok_all_monolit);
  }
  if($("#per_cok_3 img").hasClass("active") == true){
   per_cok_all_derevo = s_doma * per_cok_derevo;
   cena_per_cok = per_cok_all_derevo;
   $("#print_form .block_stroy p.per_cok>span").html(per_cok_all_derevo);
  }
 });
 $("#print_form .block_stroy_stena .block_img").on("click", "img", function(){
  $("#print_form .block_stroy_stena .block_img>img").removeClass("active"); //удаляем класс во всех вкладках
  $("#print_form .block_stroy_stena .block_img>img").css("opacity", "0.5");
  $(this).addClass("active"); //добавляем класс текущей (нажатой)
  $(this).css("opacity", "1");
  //Стены
  if($("#stena_1 img").hasClass("active") == true){
   stena_all_kirpich_250 = s_doma * stena_kirpich_250;
   cena_stena = stena_all_kirpich_250;
   $("#print_form .block_stroy p.stena>span").html(stena_all_kirpich_250);
  }
  if($("#stena_2 img").hasClass("active") == true){
   stena_all_kirpich_370 = s_doma * stena_kirpich_370;
   cena_stena = stena_all_kirpich_370;
   $("#print_form .block_stroy p.stena>span").html(stena_all_kirpich_370);
  }
  if($("#stena_3 img").hasClass("active") == true){
   stena_all_kirpich_640 = s_doma * stena_kirpich_640;
   cena_stena = stena_all_kirpich_640;
   $("#print_form .block_stroy p.stena>span").html(stena_all_kirpich_640);
  }
  if($("#stena_4 img").hasClass("active") == true){
   stena_all_kirpich_520 = s_doma * stena_kirpich_520;
   cena_stena = stena_all_kirpich_520;
   $("#print_form .block_stroy p.stena>span").html(stena_all_kirpich_520);
  }
  if($("#stena_5 img").hasClass("active") == true){
   stena_all_teplaya_keramika = s_doma * stena_teplaya_keramika;
   cena_stena = stena_all_teplaya_keramika;
   $("#print_form .block_stroy p.stena>span").html(stena_all_teplaya_keramika);
  }
  if($("#stena_6 img").hasClass("active") == true){
   stena_all_gazobeton = s_doma * stena_gazobeton;
   cena_stena = stena_all_gazobeton;
   $("#print_form .block_stroy p.stena>span").html(stena_all_gazobeton);
  }
  if($("#stena_7 img").hasClass("active") == true){
   stena_all_brus_150 = s_doma * stena_brus_150;
   cena_stena = stena_all_brus_150;
   $("#print_form .block_stroy p.stena>span").html(stena_all_brus_150);
  }
  if($("#stena_8 img").hasClass("active") == true){
   stena_all_brus_200 = s_doma * stena_brus_200;
   cena_stena = stena_all_brus_200;
   $("#print_form .block_stroy p.stena>span").html(stena_all_brus_200);
  }
  if($("#stena_9 img").hasClass("active") == true){
   stena_all_karkasnyy_dom = s_doma * stena_karkasnyy_dom;
   cena_stena = stena_all_karkasnyy_dom;
   $("#print_form .block_stroy p.stena>span").html(stena_all_karkasnyy_dom);
  }
  if($("#stena_10 img").hasClass("active") == true){
   stena_all_dom_srub = s_doma * stena_dom_srub;
   cena_stena = stena_all_dom_srub;
   $("#print_form .block_stroy p.stena>span").html(stena_all_dom_srub);
  }
 });
 $("#print_form .block_stroy_per_et .block_img").on("click", "img", function(){
  $("#print_form .block_stroy_per_et .block_img>img").removeClass("active"); //удаляем класс во всех вкладках
  $("#print_form .block_stroy_per_et .block_img>img").css("opacity", "0.5");
  $(this).addClass("active"); //добавляем класс текущей (нажатой)
  $(this).css("opacity", "1");
  //Перекрытие межэтажное
  if($("#per_et_1 img").hasClass("active") == true){
   per_et_all_zhbi = s_doma * per_et_zhbi;
   cena_per_et = per_et_all_zhbi;
   $("#print_form .block_stroy p.per_et>span").html(per_et_all_zhbi);
  }
  if($("#per_et_2 img").hasClass("active") == true){
   per_et_all_monolit = s_doma * per_et_monolit;
   cena_per_et = per_et_all_monolit;
   $("#print_form .block_stroy p.per_et>span").html(per_et_all_monolit);
  }
  if($("#per_et_3 img").hasClass("active") == true){
   per_et_all_derevo = s_doma * per_et_derevo;
   cena_per_et = per_et_all_derevo;
   $("#print_form .block_stroy p.per_et>span").html(per_et_all_derevo);
  }
 });
 $("#print_form .block_stroy_per_ch .block_img").on("click", "img", function(){
  $("#print_form .block_stroy_per_ch .block_img>img").removeClass("active"); //удаляем класс во всех вкладках
  $("#print_form .block_stroy_per_ch .block_img>img").css("opacity", "0.5");
  $(this).addClass("active"); //добавляем класс текущей (нажатой)
  $(this).css("opacity", "1");
  //Чердачное перекрытие
  if($("#per_ch_1 img").hasClass("active") == true){
   per_ch_all_zhbi = s_doma * per_ch_zhbi;
   cena_per_ch = per_ch_all_zhbi;
   $("#print_form .block_stroy p.per_ch>span").html(per_ch_all_zhbi);
  }
  if($("#per_ch_2 img").hasClass("active") == true){
   per_ch_all_monolit = s_doma * per_ch_monolit;
   cena_per_ch = per_ch_all_monolit;
   $("#print_form .block_stroy p.per_ch>span").html(per_ch_all_monolit);
  }
  if($("#per_ch_3 img").hasClass("active") == true){
   per_ch_all_derevo = s_doma * per_ch_derevo;
   cena_per_ch = per_ch_all_derevo;
   $("#print_form .block_stroy p.per_ch>span").html(per_ch_all_derevo);
  }
 });
 $("#print_form .block_stroy_krysha .block_img").on("click", "img", function(){
  $("#print_form .block_stroy_krysha .block_img>img").removeClass("active"); //удаляем класс во всех вкладках
  $("#print_form .block_stroy_krysha .block_img>img").css("opacity", "0.5");
  $(this).addClass("active"); //добавляем класс текущей (нажатой)
  $(this).css("opacity", "1");
  //Крыша
  if($("#krysha_1 img").hasClass("active") == true){
   krysha_all_metallocherepica = s_doma * krysha_metallocherepica;
   cena_krysha = krysha_all_metallocherepica;
   $("#print_form .block_stroy p.krysha>span").html(krysha_all_metallocherepica);
  }
  if($("#krysha_2 img").hasClass("active") == true){
   krysha_all_ondulin = s_doma * krysha_ondulin;
   cena_krysha = krysha_all_ondulin;
   $("#print_form .block_stroy p.krysha>span").html(krysha_all_ondulin);
  }
  if($("#krysha_3 img").hasClass("active") == true){
   krysha_all_proflist = s_doma * krysha_proflist;
   cena_krysha = krysha_all_proflist;
   $("#print_form .block_stroy p.krysha>span").html(krysha_all_proflist);
  }
  if($("#krysha_4 img").hasClass("active") == true){
   krysha_all_ker_plitka = s_doma * krysha_ker_plitka;
   cena_krysha = krysha_all_ker_plitka;
   $("#print_form .block_stroy p.krysha>span").html(krysha_all_ker_plitka);
  }
  if($("#krysha_5 img").hasClass("active") == true){
   krysha_all_myagkaya_cher = s_doma * krysha_myagkaya_cher;
   cena_krysha = krysha_all_myagkaya_cher;
   $("#print_form .block_stroy p.krysha>span").html(krysha_all_myagkaya_cher);
  }
 });
 $("#print_form .block_stroy_fasad .block_img").on("click", "img", function(){
  $("#print_form .block_stroy_fasad .block_img>img").removeClass("active"); //удаляем класс во всех вкладках
  $("#print_form .block_stroy_fasad .block_img>img").css("opacity", "0.5");
  $(this).addClass("active"); //добавляем класс текущей (нажатой)
  $(this).css("opacity", "1");
  //Отделка фасада
  if($("#fasad_1 img").hasClass("active") == true){
   fasad_all_sh_setka = s_doma * fasad_sh_setka;
   cena_fasad = fasad_all_sh_setka;
   $("#print_form .block_stroy p.fasad>span").html(fasad_all_sh_setka);
  }
  if($("#fasad_2 img").hasClass("active") == true){
   fasad_all_utepl_pokraska = s_doma * fasad_utepl_pokraska;
   cena_fasad = fasad_all_utepl_pokraska;
   $("#print_form .block_stroy p.fasad>span").html(fasad_all_utepl_pokraska);
  }
  if($("#fasad_3 img").hasClass("active") == true){
   fasad_all_decor = s_doma * fasad_decor;
   cena_fasad = fasad_all_decor;
   $("#print_form .block_stroy p.fasad>span").html(fasad_all_decor);
  }
  if($("#fasad_4 img").hasClass("active") == true){
   fasad_all_kirpich = s_doma * fasad_kirpich;
   cena_fasad = fasad_all_kirpich;
   $("#print_form .block_stroy p.fasad>span").html(fasad_all_kirpich);
  }
  if($("#fasad_5 img").hasClass("active") == true){
   fasad_all_sayding = s_doma * fasad_sayding;
   cena_fasad = fasad_all_sayding;
   $("#print_form .block_stroy p.fasad>span").html(fasad_all_sayding);
  }
 });
 $("#but_form").click(function(){
  cena_all = cena_fund + cena_per_cok + cena_stena + cena_per_et + cena_per_ch + cena_krysha + cena_fasad;
  $("#dom_rez_price_rab").html(cena_all);
  $("#rezultat").show();
$("#rezultat2").show();
 });
 //
 //
 //
 //


});
```

Вот сайт, где реализовано похожее:
https://vk.cc/9kCvab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создайте вместо переменных строительных материалов(крыша,фундамент) массив и значение под индексом 0 будет одноэтажный, а значение под индексом 1 будет 2-ух этажный дом.

```
  i = 0 or i = 1
  fund_stolb = [430,2130];
  fund_plita = [4235,5600];
  fund_stolb[i] + fund_plita[i] = ...
```

При указании какой дом будет присваиваться значение i.Каждую переменную переделайте в массив и всё).

Если не переписывать весь код нужно сделать выбор дома и присвоить значение if, дальше сделайте

```
  if(i ===1){
  // Цены одноэтажного дома
  } else {
  // Цены двухэтажного дома
  }
```

Тогда в 1 случае будут 1 переменные, в другом - другие

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Теоретически мне все понятно. Но вот практически я такое не сделаю, к сожалению) Можно пример?

Comment: Для начала переделайте все цены. Что б первое число было одноэтажный, а второе двухэтажный.

Comment: Александр, сделайте в начале выбор какой это дом. 
i = 1 или i = 2. Дальше сделайте if( i === 1) тогда создаются 1 значения.если нет , то другие

Comment: Там видите какая еще вещь. Это же все еще должно умножаться на площадь дома. Сейчас вот так: stena_all_kirpich_250 = s_doma * stena_kirpich_250;

Comment: Я правил пост можете проверить. Такой подход Вам подходит ?

Comment: А как быть с площадью?

Comment: Вынести площадь за условик(if) или создавать отдельную площать для каждого исхода событий

Comment: Можно попробовать ) Как нам можно связаться с Вами ?

Comment: alexkonovalov998 - skype

Comment: Привет! Ответь, пожалуйста, в скайп

Comment: Я тебе ещё нужен ? Прости, что не отвечал